# Xml Schema Validation fails with MemoryStream in C#

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

Here is my function.

If you pass MemoryStream to XmlReader it does not validate proper xml files sometimes. I have the XmlDocument object stored in memory, I want to validate it against the xsd Schema files provided by the end user.

```
ValidateSchema1(string XMLPath, string XSDPath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDocument.Load(XMLPath);

          using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
          {
              //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mstream);
              xmlDocument.Save(mstream);
              mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();

              // Add the schema to the collection.
              sc.Add(null, XSDPath);

              // Set the validation settings.
              XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
              settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
              settings.Schemas = sc;
              settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallBack;

              // Create the XmlReader object.

              // Not woking
              XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mstream, settings);

              // Working
              //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDocument.InnerXml), settings);

              // Working
              //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath, settings);

              // Parse the file. 
              while (reader.Read()) ;
          }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the XML is valid when validation fails? The validation exception should tell you _why_ it failed.

Answer (score 2):

This might work: 
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_CSharp/Q_23387252.html
This works
[How to validate, on runtime, xml against xsd without save the xsd file on local folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085526/how-to-validate-on-runtime-xml-against-xsd-without-save-the-xsd-file-on-local)

Edit 1: Fixed the code you provided, now the code works as it should, validated 2 of my files. The reason why you got the error is the fact that you where trying to validate and Xsd with itself and the root element wasn't there. Please check the solution to see for yourself.

```
public void Xsd_whithout_saved()  
    {  
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();  
        xmlDoc.Load(@"file.xsd");  
        //In the futute, strArquivoInteiro will be fullfill by xsd comming from   database as nvarchar(max) and I will //not be allowed to save as a file locally    
        string strArquivoInteiro = xmlDoc.OuterXml;  

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strArquivoInteiro);
        MemoryStream streamXSD = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        //<<<
        streamXSD.Position = 0;
        StreamReader readerXsd = new StreamReader(streamXSD);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += this.MyValidationEventHandler;

        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(readerXsd));
        settings.CheckCharacters = true;

        XmlReader XmlValidatingReader = XmlReader.Create(@"file.xml", settings);

        XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader(@"file.xsd");
        //Created another reader for xml to use for validation
        XmlTextReader Reader2 = new XmlTextReader(@"file.xml");

        XmlSchema Schema = new XmlSchema();

        //IN THIS LINE I RECEIVED THE XmlException "Root Element is Missing" and I can't understand the reason
        //This was the first problem, a xsd root element isn't equal to an xml root element , and you where trying to validate and xsd with xsd here, and of course the error.
        Schema = XmlSchema.Read(Reader, MyValidationEventHandler);

        XmlValidatingReader ValidatingReader = new XmlValidatingReader(Reader2);

        ValidatingReader.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        ValidatingReader.Schemas.Add(Schema);

        try
        {

            XmlValidatingReader.Read();
            XmlValidatingReader.Close();

            ValidatingReader.ValidationEventHandler += MyValidationEventHandler;

            while ((ValidatingReader.Read()))
            {

            }

            ValidatingReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ValidatingReader.Close();
            XmlValidatingReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the other two commented out methods in your code instead of memory stream?

[UPDATE]:

Try this answer:

```
    public static bool ValidateXmlFromXsd(string xml, string xsdFile)
    {

        bool returned = false;
        XmlValidatingReader reader = null;
        XmlSchemaCollection myschema = new XmlSchemaCollection();
        ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ShowCompileErrors);
        try
        {
            XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(null, null, "", XmlSpace.None);
            reader = new XmlValidatingReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Element, context);
            myschema.Add("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata", xsdFile);
            reader.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            reader.Schemas.Add(myschema);

            while (reader.Read()) { }

            Console.WriteLine("Completed validating xmlfragment");
            returned = true;
        }
        catch (XmlException XmlExp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(XmlExp.Message);
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaException XmlSchExp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(XmlSchExp.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception GenExp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GenExp.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Read();
        }
        return returned;
    }
```

Comment: Because the offered solution I cannot use with the classes I already have.

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvote? That's just a suggestion, not an answer!

Comment: You could have posted a comment, not an answer

Comment: I will try this when I get home.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. There is also a problem, almost all classes you use are obsolete and soon they will dissapear