# How to deserialize multiple objects from a json stream?

Tags: c#, .net, json, twitter, streaming

Ok, I have asked questions about something like this before, but this is a different subject, so i feel i should make a new topic about it. I'm sorry if this is something i should not have done...

Anyway:

I'm currently reading a twitterfeed and trying to convert it to lose (status) objects. The code i have now is as follows but fails:

```
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(stream_url);
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
webRequest.Timeout = -1;
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), encode);
int i = 0;

//Read the stream.
while (_running)
{
    jsonText = responseStream.ReadLine();

    byte[] sd = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonText);
    stream.Write(sd, i, i + sd.Length);

    try
    {
        status s = json.ReadObject(stream) as status;
        if (s != null)
        {
            //write s to a file/collection or w/e
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

}
```

The idea is: Copy the stream into another stream. and keep trying to read it untill an status object is discovered.
This was ment to prevent the stream for being to little, so it had chance to grow. Ofcourse the stream does not always start at the start of an object, or can be corrupt.

Now i did find the method `IsStartObject`, and i think i should use it.
Though i have no experience with streams and i can never find a good example of how to use this.

Is there anyone who can explain to me how to read multiple objects from the stream so i can write them into a list or w/e. I really can't find any good examples on the internets..

Thank you very much for trying!!!

Comment: I am not sure that I can understand, why dont you read all response `responseStream.ReadToEnd()` and deserialize to a class (or parse)?

Comment: It's an endless stream (the twitter feed). And the Status object is a class i want to deserialize to. But the stream keeps streaming these objects (without end).

Comment: Can you share the url so that we can test it?

Comment: Sure! just use https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json in combination with any twitter user/pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library and [this extension class](http://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA) that makes use of `DynamicObject` to parse streaming json objects

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json");
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "......");
webRequest.Timeout = -1;
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

string line;
while (true)
{
    line = responseStream.ReadLine();
    dynamic obj = JsonUtils.JsonObject.GetDynamicJsonObject(line);
    if(obj.user!=null)
        Console.WriteLine(obj.user.screen_name + " => " + obj.text);
}
```

Comment: Very usefull answer! Thank you very much, this is exactly what i needed:)

One question though: can it happen that the parsing to a dynamic json object happends slower then the stream is comming in, which wil result in the stream being buffered in memory?
If so: how can i solve this?

Comment: It is a producer-comsumer problem. You can run the reader in a separate thread, put the `line`s to a queue(ex, BlockingQueue) and the main thread can read the lines from that queue and create a dynamic object(you can even process the `line`s in BlockingQueue with many threads)

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more noob question though: is it normal that one object is in one line? When i started i was just expecting parts of data...like it reads untill half way an objects, then next line is next part etc...is it always this easy or is that just different depending on the provider of the stream?

Comment: It depends on the provider. Twiitter makes the life easy for you.

Comment: Makes me wonder how to do it if it was the hell i discribed....are there examples/tutorials that you know of?

Comment: I don't think. It is application/protocol/developer dependent. But if you talk of streaming json objects(as a pure text), you can try to count the nesting levels of `{` and `}`. Start with 0, increment the counter with `{` and decrement with `}`. if the count is zero you have reached the end of the object and you can deserialize it (Just a quick thought)

Comment: any idea how to do this in .net 3.5?

Answer (score -1):

This is an implementation of [L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b%20L.B)'s suggestion for splitting by counting the nesting level of { and }.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> JsonSplit(this StreamReader input, char openChar = '{', char closeChar = '}',
  char quote='"', char escape='\\')
{
  var accumulator = new StringBuilder();
  int count = 0;
  bool gotRecord = false;
  bool inString = false;
  while (!input.EndOfStream)
  {
    char c = (char)input.Read();
    if (c == escape)
    {
      accumulator.Append(c);
      c = (char)input.Read();
    }
    else if (c == quote)
    {
      inString = !inString;
    }
    else if (inString)
    {
    }
    else if (c == openChar)
    {
      gotRecord = true;
      count++;
    }
    else if (c == closeChar)
    {
      count--;
    }
    accumulator.Append(c);
    if (count != 0 || !gotRecord) continue;
    // now we are not within a block so 
    string result = accumulator.ToString();
    accumulator.Clear();
    gotRecord = false;
    yield return result;
  }
}
```

Here's a test

```
[TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      string text = "{\"a\":1}{\"b\":\"hello\"}{\"c\":\"oh}no!\"}{\"d\":\"and\\\"also!\"}";
      var reader = FromStackOverflow.GenerateStreamFromString(text);
      var e = MyJsonExtensions.JsonSplit(reader).GetEnumerator();
      e.MoveNext();
      Assert.AreEqual("{\"a\":1}", e.Current);
      e.MoveNext();
      Assert.AreEqual("{\"b\":\"hello\"}", e.Current);
      e.MoveNext();
      Assert.AreEqual("{\"c\":\"oh}no!\"}", e.Current);
      e.MoveNext();
      Assert.AreEqual("{\"d\":\"and\\\"also!\"}", e.Current);
    }
  }
```

The implementation of GenerateStreamFromString is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-to-generate-a-stream-from-a-string)

Comment: This would fail if your openChar/closeChar happens to be in a string.
E.G. {"a":1}{"b":"hello"}{"c":"oh}no!"}

Comment: Thanks @GraemeJob. Whilst not wishing to write a json parser I've updated my answer to handle the obvious gotchas.