# Error in htmlparser cannot take string reader as input?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

In the following code, `Parse` cannot take `StringReader` (`sr`) as input. How can I pass the string I have to `Parse`, then?

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);          

    string str = "<h1 title=’Header’ align=’Center’> Writing To PDF Using ASP.NET> <br><table align=’Center’><tr><td style=’width:100px;color:green’> <b>iTextSharp</b></td><td style=’width:100px;color:red’>mytestpdf</td></tr></table>";
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(str);
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0.0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);//Parse cannot take input as string reader (sr) how to solve?
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: And the question is? Oh, I see the question burried in the code. Please reformat the question to make it more readable. See [Ask] and [FAQ] page for more information.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readtoend.aspx

Comment: i am using itextsharp for convert to pdf.i get error in htmlparse.parse(sr).

Comment: 1Error 83 The best overloaded method match for   'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.Parse(System.IO.StreamReader)' has some invalid arguments 

2.Error 84 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.StringReader' to 'System.IO.StreamReader'

Comment: What version of .net are you targeting and what version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: yes it is problem of version..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting your html into a StringReader?  You already have the html in a string, just use that.

```
htmlparser.Parse(str)
```

If you must use StringReader for some reason, use the [ReadToEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readtoend.aspx) method to get a data type HTMLWorker.Parse will accept:

```
htmlparser.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd())
```

Comment: when i modify the code.. i got error                                     cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.StreamReader

Comment: Consult this question for information on how to convert a string to a StreamReader:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-to-generate-a-stream-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

I update the itextsharp 5.0.. ..
now it not showing errors..