# Value of type 'iTextSharp.text.Document' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext

i'm Using iTextSharp to generate a PDF. but the problem is that my code is working fine in c# but when i convert that code in vb then it shows 2 errors

Please Ignore some Extra Coding and comments 
Code i'm using

```
 Dim Response As HttpResponse = SelectedGridView.Page.Response
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & FileName)
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        SelectedGridView.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader("<html><body>" & sw.ToString() & "</body></html>")
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F) 
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = Nothing
        pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        Try
           XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWrite, pdfDoc, sr) 
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        'htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.[End]()
```

And The Error

[image]

Last Edited Image :

[image]
What Should i do ?

Comment: Which version of XML Worker are you using?

Comment: Is that third argument supposed to be a `stream`?  Because a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isn't a [`stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you need to convert a string to a stream, do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-to-generate-a-stream-from-a-string

Comment: version of XML 5.5.3.0

Comment: In (deleted) comments, you claim that you are using 5.1.2. Now you say you are using 5.5.3. First make sure that you are using 5.5.3 for both iTextSharp **and** XML Worker. Then look at the comment posted by @dbc: you need a *stream*, not a *reader*. Your problem is caused by bad coding hygiene. Please start afresh (from scratch, with a clean project).

Comment: Yap U got solution There was version problem Thanks @Bruno and all

Comment: Also, do not do this, `Response.Write(pdfDoc)`, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

- I downloaded the dll file for iTextSharp from http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/?source=typ_redirect and xmlworker from http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/
- Extracted them and right click on the solution in Solution Explorer and then add -> reference and in  browse tab add your dll file.