# myBB Passwords c# client

Tags: c#

I'm working on a loader / client where my forum users will use their myBB information to login to my application. I know it's not good to have the database connection in the application. But I am also going to store their hwid on the database so I would need to connect to it anyway.

However, they store the passwords like this:

```
$hashedpsw = md5(md5($salt).md5($plainpassword));
```

And my attempt to recreate that passwords looks like this:

```
string salt = "D4UFUd6U"; // get salt from db
string password = "test!";// get password from user
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

// Create md5 hash of salt
byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(salt);
byte[] saltHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(salt);
string saltHash = System.BitConverter.ToString(saltHashBytes);

// Create your md5(password + md5(salt)) hash
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password + saltHash);
byte[] passwordHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(salt);
string passwordHash = BitConverter.ToString(passwordHashBytes);
```

But I get the following error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Comment: On which line do you get an error?

Comment: byte[] saltHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(salt);` and `byte[] passwordHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(salt);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ComputeHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19(v=vs.110).aspx) wants an `IO.Stream`  or a `Byte[]` as input, and as the error specifies, can't convert from your strings to `IO.Stream` implicitly.

The following is an example of how you can convert a string to a stream (stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879470/54527)):

```
public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

This would alter your code to the following:

```
string salt = "D4UFUd6U"; // get salt from db
string password = "test!";// get password from user
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

// Create md5 hash of salt
byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(salt);
byte[] saltHashBytes;
using( Stream saltStream = GenerateStreamFromString(salt))
{
    salteHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(saltStream);
}
string saltHash = System.BitConverter.ToString(saltHashBytes);

// Create your md5(password + md5(salt)) hash
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password + saltHash);
byte[] passwordHashBytes;
using( Stream saltStream = GenerateStreamFromString(salt))
{
    passwordHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(saltStream);
}
string passwordHash = BitConverter.ToString(passwordHashBytes);
```

Comment: Anytime you use a stream, it is always recommended that you wrap it in a using statement so that it is properly closed when you're finished with it, even if an exception is thrown.
byte[] saltHashBytes;
            using(Stream saltStream = GenerateStreamFromString(salt)) { saltHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(saltStream); }

Comment: Edited.  I didn't put in code to check if the *HashBytes array variable is null before it is passed into the BitConverter.ToString() method though.

Comment: You've got to leave at least something as an exercise to the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

You use the `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` class to encrypt using `md5` hash algorithm. First add the following namespaces:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Second, try a function like this.

```
public static string Encrypt(string content)
{
   MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
   bytes = md5.ComputeHash(data);
   string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
   return result;
}
```