# Convert System.Drawing.Image from Stream -- Parameter not valid

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert

> System.Drawing.Image from Stream

but its throwing `Parameter not valid exception.`

```
 Stream p_sImageStream = GenerateStreamFromString(p_sImage);
 System.Drawing.Image oIM = Bitmap.FromStream(p_sImageStream);
```

my p_sImage is `"56427673422d0cbd5dfdfebc_M-19__wide-1.JPG"`

Comment: A drawing is a binary file and you should never convert it to a string.  Binary data should always use Encoding UTF8 and be converted to a byte[] instead of a string.  Most string classes default to Encoding Ascii which will corrupt binary data.  So make sure you specify the encoding when using binary data.

Comment: thats y i m converting it to a stream first and then drawing. where am 
I going wrong.

Comment: show code for `GenerateStreamFromString()`

Comment: That is not a "stream", that is a filename.  Use Image.FromFile() instead.

Comment: @jstreet: Probably gotten from http://stackoverflow.com/q/1879395/103167

Answer (score 2):

The parameter to `GenerateStreamFromString` is not a filename, it's expected to contain the actual data.

If you have the filename of a JPEG file, use `File.OpenRead` to get a stream you can pass to `Bitmap.FromStream`, or else just use `new Bitmap(filename)` -- this constructor overload opens and reads a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string p_sImage = @"c:\temp\56427673422d0cbd5dfdfebc_M-19__wide-1.JPG";
FileStream stream = new FileStream(p_sImage, FileMode.Open);
System.Drawing.Image oIM = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
```