# convert string csv to List of objects

Tags: c#, string, parsing, csv

I have the following sting

```
const string csv = "Foo1,Foo2,Foo3,Foo4,Foo5,Foo6,Ping Pong\n" +
                   "2016-02-29,1437.530029,1445.839966,1433.77002,1436.930054,34016300,1436.930054\n" +
                   "2016-02-25,1431.439941,1431.439941,1421.280029,1426.97998,78076500,1426.97998\n" +
                   "2016-02-24,1430.459961,1432.430054,1417.449951,1419.790039,29049900,1419.790039\n";
```

How I can convert it to `List<Model>`
where

```
public class Model
{
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }
    public string Foo2 { get; set; }
    public string Foo3 { get; set; }
    public string Foo4 { get; set; }
    public string Foo5 { get; set; }
    public string Foo6 { get; set; }
    public string Ping_Pong { get; set; }
}
```

**Note of the `Ping Pong` header in my orig csv**

I tried to use [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) but with no success as it is taking a stream rather then string and I failed trying to convert a parse

**EDIT** It does not matter for me if to use CsvHelper or not, in the end I want to convert the csv to `List<Model>`

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you implement custom parsing logic here?

Comment: Or you could convert the string to a stream easy enough: var ms = new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(csv));

Comment: There are ways to convert a `string` to a `Stream` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-to-generate-a-stream-from-a-string

Comment: I would recommend that you don't give up with csvhelper -- I've had a lot of success with it.  It can take a TextReader, and you can surface your string with a reader by using a StringReader:  var myReader = new StringReader(thecsvString):

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create an `StringReader` using `csv` variable:

```
var textReader = new StringReader(csv);

var csvr = new CsvReader(textReader);
var records = csvr.GetRecords<Model>();
```

If you want your own parser:

```
var lines = csv.Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1);
List<Model> models = new List<Model>();

foreach (var item in lines)
{
    var values = item.Split(',');
    var model = new Model
    {
        Foo1 = values[0],
        Foo2 = values[1],
        Foo3 = values[2],
        Foo4 = values[3],
        Foo5 = values[4],
        Foo6 = values[5],
        Ping_Pong = values[6],
    };

    models.Add(model);
}
```

**EDIT:**

To resolve the header problem using `CsvHelper` you need create a map configuration class specifying the mappings between headers and properties:

```
public class ModelMap : CsvClassMap<Model>
{
    public ModelMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Foo1);
        Map(m => m.Foo2);
        Map(m => m.Foo3);
        Map(m => m.Foo4);
        Map(m => m.Foo5);
        Map(m => m.Foo6);
        Map(m => m.Ping_Pong).Name("Ping Pong");
    }
}
```

Using like this:

```
var textReader = new StringReader(csv);

var csvr = new CsvReader(textReader);
csvr.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ModelMap>();

var records = csvr.GetRecords<Model>();
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, my question is how can I assign the header to the correct property in class Model? I prefer instead of reading the [x] place

Comment: You could just do `csv.Split('\n')` using the `Split(params char[] separators)` overload since you don't really need to remove empty entries for the OP's example.

Comment: @juharr: was my first try but `csv` has a `\n` at the end. params overload returned an empty line at the end.

Comment: Somehow when testing your second answer is not working for me. var records = csvr.GetRecords<StockModel>(); gives me null

Comment: @user829174: StockModel is the same as Model? if not note you need create the map inheriting from CsvClassMap<StockModel>

Comment: yes, StockModel is Model, sorry for confusing you, I copy paste.. still not working

Comment: @user829174: returns null or object properties are null?

Comment: when hover records with debugger I get records.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current = null. I want to return List<Model>

Comment: @user829174: try with this `var records = csvr.GetRecords<Model>().ToList();` to convert explicitly to a list

Comment: awesome, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data set (the csv string) is missing a column (you specify 7 columns, but the Ping Pong column is missing from the csv).  The default behavior will be to throw, but you can set a config option to ignore missing columns:

Here's working code:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration();
// setting this will cause the missing Ping Pong field to be ignored
config.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;

// we wrap your string in a StringReader to make it accessible to CsvReader
var reader = new CsvReader(new StringReader(csv), config);
var records = reader.GetRecords<Model>().ToList();
records.Dump();
```

Comment: I do have 'Ping Pong' data, I doubled checked in my question. I have 7 values in header (where ping pong has space in between) and 7 values in data

Comment: @user829174 You're right, I miscounted.  I renamed your header from "Ping Pong" to "Ping_Pong", so it matches your model, and now all 7 columns parse

Answer (score -1):

To do exactly what you asked you could use this:

```
var modelStrings = csv.Split('\n').Skip(1);
var models = new List<Model>();
foreach(string s in modelStrings)
{
    var props = s.Split(',');
    models.Add(new Model(props[0],props[1],props[2],props[3],props[4],props[5],props[6]));

}
```

but a word of warning: this is probably slow, and you might need to add more extensive logic for instantiating new models to account for possible changes in csv format.

Edit:

To clarify what this does, it first splits the csv string by new lines skipping the first one. Then it uses each string in that list and splits them by commas to get a list of values (model properties) to instantiate the Model class with

Comment: not sure it will work, what is 'foreach(string s in models)'?

Comment: whoops i changed a variable name, let me edit my answer

Comment: Your first split would also split on the space in "Ping Pong".

Comment: One reason I like using a library like csvreader instead of parsing by hand, is that the reader will handle data that is in Excel's csv format.  That may or may not matter for the OP's use, but here's an example:  if one of the data values is a comma (so you want that comma, it's not a separator), Excel would put that value in quotes, and you would ignore any commas inside the quotes.  CsvHelper has all that parsing logic built in.  Just something to know -- could be overkill for the OP's need, but might not be.

Comment: @juharr ah ok I believe I misinterpreted the information on the docs on Split, I updated it so it shouldn't be an issue anymore

Comment: Since the `Split` overload you are using is `Split(params char[] seperators)` you don't have to create an array, so `csv.Split('\n')` would do the same thing.