# Deserializing as DataContract from string value in memory

Tags: c#, json, string, stream, datacontractserializer

I have the following code (which works) to deserialize raw json received from a web call :

```
public static async Task<Example> GetExample() {
    Example record = new Example();

    using ( WebClient wc = new WebClient() ) {
        wc.Headers.Add( "Accept", "application/json" );

        try {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( Example ) );
            using ( Stream s = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync( "https://example.com/sample.json" ) ) {
                record = ser.ReadObject( s ) as Example;
            }
        } catch ( SerializationException se ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( se.Message );
        } catch ( WebException we ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( we.Message );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( e.Message );
        }
    }
    return record;
}
```

However, I have a different scenario where the data I am working with is encrypted so I need to decode base64, then decrypt the result to get the json data.

To keep it simple, assume that the following is the string received from the server ( base64 encoded only ) :

```
 ew0KICAidG9tIjogIjEyMyINCn0=
```

Which decodes with (stored in `foo`)

```
 string foo = Convert.FromBase64String("ew0KICAidG9tIjogIjEyMyINCn0=");
```

How do I pass `foo` to `.ReadObject()` as `.ReadObject()` only accepts `Stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it back into a stream and pass the stream to `ReadObject`. You can use a `MemoryStream` as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879470/871910) .

Following is an example as an anonymous type method :

```
/// <summary>
/// Read json from string into class with DataContract properties
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">DataContract class</typeparam>
/// <param name="json">JSON as a string</param>
/// <param name="encoding">Text encoding format (example Encoding.UTF8)</param>
/// <param name="settings">DataContract settings (can be used to set datetime format, etc)</param>
/// <returns>DataContract class populated with serialized json data</returns>
public static T FromString<T>( string json, Encoding encoding, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings ) where T : class {
    T result = null;
    try {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( T ), settings );
        using ( Stream s = new MemoryStream( ( encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8 ).GetBytes( json ?? "" ) ) ) {
            result = ser.ReadObject( s ) as T;
        }
    } catch ( SerializationException se ) {
        Debug.WriteLine( se.Message );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        Debug.WriteLine( e.Message );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is good.  Will test this out later.  If the code there works for this will modify your solution and mark as accepted.  In the meantime, I have upvoted as it looks like what I was looking for.  :)

Comment: Added an example in the form of an anonymous type method for re-use.  Sorry for the delay in updating with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try yhis:

```
using ( Stream s = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync( "https://example.com/sample.json" ) ) 
{
    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s.GetBuffer(),0 , s.GetBuffer().Length)
    string foo = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
}
```

Comment: `foo` needs to be converted to a `Stream` as `.ReadObject()` accepts only objects of type `Stream`.

Comment: @KraangPrime - Once got foo, refer to *zmbq* answer to generate a stream from foo.