# Converting a StreamReader(String) to be compatible with UWP API?

Tags: c#, class, uwp, streamreader

I'm running into a snag utilizing the StreamReader class. On the [StreamReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) documentation page, it states that it 
supports Universal Windows Platforms (UWPs) under the Version Information header, "Universal Windows Platform - Available since 8".

Upon further inspection of its constructors, the StreamReader(Stream) constructors do support UWP apps, however the [StreamReader(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx) constructors do not support them.

I'm currently using the StreamReader(String) constructor with the complete file path to to be read,

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    ...
}
```

I'm seeking to learn how to convert my code for a StreamReader(String) to a StreamReader(Stream).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-to-generate-a-stream-from-a-string) what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Is you string a filename or a string. To read a string use StringReader(string).  The string in a StreamReader is a filename.

Comment: @Kilazur, in a sense yes. I want to use the path.

Comment: @jdweng, right but if you read the question carefully it specifies that StreamReader(string) is not supported by UWPs. Thus I was looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP `StreamReader` accepts only `Stream` with additional Options. Not String.

So to use `StreamReader` from a particular path, you need to get the `StorageFile`

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(<Your path>);
var randomAccessStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving my own problem! The documentation is spot on.

From

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    ...
}
```

To

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Simple and elegant. Thanks again to all who contributed!

Comment: You'll get an ACCESS_DENIED error if the path is outside of the app folders.

Comment: Welcome to the [sandboxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) environment! You need to get an instance of [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile), usually through a [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker), then use the method in AVK's answer. You cannot access files directly using a path.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz I believe that is exactly what is happening to me... Is there a workaround or known solution? I need to be able to access files outside of the builds app folders as its a dynamic program that will work for any user. Would any of [FileStreams params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) work here?

Comment: No, You need to use the StorageFile to get an stream to the file if it is outside of app folders.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz "You need to get an instance of StorageFile, usually through a FileOpenPicker". The documentation on FileOpenPicker here is quite dense. Would you draft a prototype example here to illustrate how you mean?

Comment: [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-Picker-in-Windows-10-846c2116#content) you can find a sample.

Comment: Hmm.. well I seem to get errors from the await methods, and the script doesn't work without them either.