# How to create SHA256 hash from a string

Tags: vb.net, encryption, cryptography, passwords, sha256

I need to create a sha256 hash of a password entered in a `TextBox`. I tried to use `ComputeHash(string)` but it only works with streams.

Comment: This could give you the tip needed.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-do-i-generate-a-stream-from-a-string

Comment: @Steve link is good for starters, but if looking at the accepted answer there, remember the encoding isn't in place and which may be of importance.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ yes, there is a very important comment under the accepted answer and the second upvoted answer addresses it even better.

Comment: Maybe: `Dim hash = New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The-password"))`. Also check [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yeah, this is a method with a few overloads, so the "only works with streams" part is a bad preconception. And more importantly, the idea that you use a cryptographic hash on a password is probably another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim hash = New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The-password"))
```