# Can't find xml file in unity

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read an already existing xml file with tasks in my game. If I use `xmlDoc.Load(Application.dataPath + $"/Resources/XML/tasks1.xml");` then everything works in the editor, but does not work in the finished version on android.
I have read about the possibility of using `persistentDataPath` but it does not work. The file is not searched in the editor and on the device. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void LoadTasks()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(Application.persistentDataPath + $"/Resources/XML/Russian/{BurronController.mode}.xml");
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
        XmlNode trueNode = nodes[0];
        XmlNode doNode = nodes[1];

        trueTasks = new string[trueNode.ChildNodes.Count];
        doTasks = new string[doNode.ChildNodes.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < trueTasks.Length; i++)
        {
            trueTasks[i] = trueNode.ChildNodes[i].InnerText;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < doTasks.Length; i++)
        {
            doTasks[i] = doNode.ChildNodes[i].InnerText;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the API for [`Application.datPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)

> **Android**: Normally it points directly to the APK. If you are running a split binary build, it points to the OBB instead.

It is the apk path and you can not simply access files packed in there.

and [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

> **Android**: Application.persistentDataPath points to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data//files on most devices (some older phones might point to location on SD card if present), the path is resolved using android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir.

=> unless you explicitly have put your file here there is nothing to load from.

In the editor itself you have external access to your file system and can use both if the file is located in according path.

---

Further you are using `Resources` - in general [**Do not use it**](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7). Nowadays you would rather go for [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.3/manual/AddressableAssetsOverview.html).

Anyway also refer to according API for [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html)

=> You get assets from there via [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) / [`Resources.LoadAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html) where the path would rather be e.g.

```
var xmlAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>($"XML/Russian/{BurronController.mode}");
```

from there you can now either directly load the xml string via [`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml)

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlAsset.text);
```

or you could go for [`XmlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader) via a [`MemoryStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-do-i-generate-a-stream-from-a-string)

Or you could copy it over to the `persistentDataPath` **if you want** your users to be able to manipulate the file and then lo from the file via you original attempt